# Terminal command through python hanging after opening program

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I'm starting a program with its command using python but after the command has been executed the script gets stucked and only continues when I close the window that's been opened.
So, if i do something very simple like this:

```
    import os
    os.system('gedit')
    print('aaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

It won't print until I close the text editor.
The same happens with `subprocess.call`

Comment: It doesn't get hanged. It's doing in the correct way. You opened the editor using the `os.system('gedit')`. You didn't pass any close commands.  So it is holding up there

Comment: But how can I move on without closing the window?

Comment: change this line of code `os.system('gedit &')`. It will be run in the background. You can move on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a working code which does what you want.

I have tested it on a RedHat 7 Linux and it worked as expected.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["gedit"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print("STDOUT: {0} \nSTDERR: {1}".format(stdout, stderr))
print("After I closed Gedit")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
STDOUT: b'' 
STDERR: b'\n(gedit:683047): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: 08:20:31.346: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor is not supported\n'
After I closed Gedit
```

NOTE: Of course, the Gedit has opened and when I closed it the program runned continue.